# PHP Update 8.0 to 8.1: Doctrine Annotations Parser Error

Tags: php, doctrine

Does anyone happen to know what has changed from PHP 8.0 to 8.1 in terms of the old Doctrine annotations? I have a legacy code with Doctrine annotations that I need to migrate temporarily to PHP 8.1. The whole thing is now running under PHP 8.0.

Under PHP 8.1 the following error occurs:

```
Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, 
got 'CLASS' at position 25 in class @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity.
```

The following annotation is no longer interpreted correctly by the lexer/parser

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target("CLASS")
 */
```

As I said, it worked under 8.0 - nothing was changed in the code/libraries. My guess is that under PHP 8.1 either the comments are interpreted differently (double quotes?) or a comparison operation (==) has changed. I think that the double quotes are no longer recognized correctly.
It is a quick, temporary solution. The complete code conversion with current Doctrine versions is in progress, but will take some time due to the complexity of the project.

Full error stack:

```
{
            "file": "\/html\/frontend\/www\/backend\/vendor\/doctrine\/annotations\/lib\/Doctrine\/Common\/Annotations\/DocParser.php",
            "line": 445,
            "function": "syntaxError",
            "class": "Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\AnnotationException",
            "type": "::",
            "args": [
                "Expected Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got \u0027CLASS\u0027 at position 25 in class @Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\Entity."
            ]
        },
        {
            "file": "\/html\/frontend\/www\/backend\/vendor\/doctrine\/annotations\/lib\/Doctrine\/Common\/Annotations\/DocParser.php",
            "line": 399,
            "function": "syntaxError",
            "class": "Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\DocParser",
            "type": "-\u003E",
            "args": [
                "Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS"
            ]
        },
        {
            "file": "\/html\/frontend\/www\/backend\/vendor\/doctrine\/annotations\/lib\/Doctrine\/Common\/Annotations\/DocParser.php",
            "line": 863,
            "function": "match",
            "class": "Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\DocParser",
            "type": "-\u003E",
            "args": [
                103
            ]
        },
        {
            "file": "\/html\/frontend\/www\/backend\/vendor\/doctrine\/annotations\/lib\/Doctrine\/Common\/Annotations\/DocParser.php",
            "line": 770,
            "function": "MethodCall",
            "class": "Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\DocParser",
            "type": "-\u003E",
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "file": "\/html\/frontend\/www\/backend\/vendor\/doctrine\/annotations\/lib\/Doctrine\/Common\/Annotations\/DocParser.php",
            "line": 654,
            "function": "Annotation",
            "class": "Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\DocParser",
            "type": "-\u003E",
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "file": "\/html\/frontend\/www\/backend\/vendor\/doctrine\/annotations\/lib\/Doctrine\/Common\/Annotations\/DocParser.php",
            "line": 359,
            "function": "Annotations",
            "class": "Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\DocParser",
            "type": "-\u003E",
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "file": "\/html\/frontend\/www\/backend\/vendor\/doctrine\/annotations\/lib\/Doctrine\/Common\/Annotations\/DocParser.php",
            "line": 515,
            "function": "parse",
            "class": "Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\DocParser",
            "type": "-\u003E",
            "args": [
                "\/**\r\n * @Annotation\r\n * @Target(\u0022CLASS\u0022)\r\n *\/",
                "class @Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\Entity"
            ]
        },
        {
            "file": "\/html\/frontend\/www\/backend\/vendor\/doctrine\/annotations\/lib\/Doctrine\/Common\/Annotations\/DocParser.php",
            "line": 744,
            "function": "collectAnnotationMetadata",
            "class": "Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\DocParser",
            "type": "-\u003E",
            "args": [
                "Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\Entity"
            ]
        },
        {
            "file": "\/html\/frontend\/www\/backend\/vendor\/doctrine\/annotations\/lib\/Doctrine\/Common\/Annotations\/DocParser.php",
            "line": 654,
            "function": "Annotation",
            "class": "Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\DocParser",
            "type": "-\u003E",
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "file": "\/html\/frontend\/www\/backend\/vendor\/doctrine\/annotations\/lib\/Doctrine\/Common\/Annotations\/DocParser.php",
            "line": 359,
            "function": "Annotations",
            "class": "Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\DocParser",
            "type": "-\u003E",
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "file": "\/html\/frontend\/www\/backend\/vendor\/doctrine\/annotations\/lib\/Doctrine\/Common\/Annotations\/AnnotationReader.php",
            "line": 221,
            "function": "parse",
            "class": "Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\DocParser",
            "type": "-\u003E",
            "args": [
                "\/**\n * @ORM\\Entity\n * @ORM\\Table(name=\u0022appointment\u0022)\n * @PIM\\Config(label=\u0022Termine\u0022, labelProperty=\u0022title\u0022, sortBy=\u0022bookedDate\u0022, tabs=\u0022{\u0027contact\u0027: \u0027Kundendaten\u0027}\u0022, sort=10)\n *\/",
                "class Custom\\Entity\\Appointment\\Appointment"
            ]
        },
        {
            "file": "\/html\/frontend\/www\/backend\/lib\/contentfly\/Classes\/Api.php",
            "line": 1414,
            "function": "getClassAnnotations",
            "class": "Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\AnnotationReader",
            "type": "-\u003E",
            "args": [
                {
                    "name": "Custom\\Entity\\Appointment\\Appointment"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Please share the full error stack, from your error message, it seems like it is nothing about the comment block itself.

Comment: See above - full stack

Answer (score 0):

this may not be a working answer, but have you tried this syntax:

```php
/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target({"CLASS"})
 */
```

Have you run `composer upgrade` in `html/frontend/www/backend/` to upgrade PHP libraries in the `vendor` folder to a version supporting PHP 8.1 ?

As for working with legacy code, I strongly recommend using [Rector](https://getrector.com/) to update the code to PHP 8.1 standard.

You may also want to look into a static code analyser such as [Psalm](https://psalm.dev/) or [PHPStan](https://phpstan.org/).

Install Rector:

```bash
command composer require --dev 'rector/rector'
```

Launch Rector a first time to generate a default configuration file
(`rector.php`):

```bash
command php 'vendor/bin/rector' 'process' --dry-run
```

An example Rector configuration (in `rector.php`) for a Symfony project is:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Rector\CodeQuality\Rector\Class_\InlineConstructorDefaultToPropertyRector;
use Rector\Config\RectorConfig;
use Rector\Doctrine\Set\DoctrineSetList;
use Rector\Set\ValueObject\LevelSetList;
use Rector\Set\ValueObject\SetList;
use Rector\Symfony\Bridge\Symfony\Routing\SymfonyRoutesProvider;
use Rector\Symfony\CodeQuality\Rector\ClassMethod\ActionSuffixRemoverRector;
use Rector\Symfony\Contract\Bridge\Symfony\Routing\SymfonyRoutesProviderInterface;
use Rector\Symfony\Set\SymfonySetList;

return static function (RectorConfig $rectorConfig): void {
    $rectorConfig->paths([
        __DIR__.'/config',
        __DIR__.'/public',
        __DIR__.'/src',
        __DIR__.'/tests',
    ]);

    // register a single rule
    $rectorConfig->rule(InlineConstructorDefaultToPropertyRector::class);

    // Provide Symfony XML Service List.
    $rectorConfig->symfonyContainerXml(__DIR__.'/var/cache/dev/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml');
    // define sets of rules
    $rectorConfig->sets([
        SetList::DEAD_CODE,
        LevelSetList::UP_TO_PHP_81,
        DoctrineSetList::DOCTRINE_CODE_QUALITY,
        DoctrineSetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
        DoctrineSetList::GEDMO_ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
        DoctrineSetList::DOCTRINE_ORM_214,
        DoctrineSetList::DOCTRINE_DBAL_30,
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_64,
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_CODE_QUALITY,
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_CONSTRUCTOR_INJECTION,
    ]);

    // Provide Symfony PHP container.
    $rectorConfig->symfonyContainerPhp(__DIR__.'/tests/RectorSymfonyContainer.php');

    // Add Symfony Route annotation config.
    $rectorConfig->singleton(SymfonyRoutesProvider::class);
    $rectorConfig->alias(SymfonyRoutesProvider::class, SymfonyRoutesProviderInterface::class);

    // skip ActionSuffixRemoverRector for SonataAdmin Controler.
    $rectorConfig->skip([
        ActionSuffixRemoverRector::class => [
            __DIR__.'/src/*/Controller/Admin/*Controller.php',
        ],
    ]);
};
```

Adjust this configuration to your PHP, Symfony, `doctrine/orm` and `doctrine/dbal` versions (or remove references to Symfony if your project don't use Symfony), and see the changes proposed by Rector:

```bash
php 'vendor/bin/rector' 'process' --dry-run
```

(See supported DoctrineSetList constants in [DoctrineSetList.php @ GitHub](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector-doctrine/blob/main/src/Set/DoctrineSetList.php)).